# selectpicker on change doesn't work after reloading partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, .net-core, asp.net-ajax

Using .net core 2.0 and razor pages.

I have a two Select Pickers that are in a partial and are loaded with two different date ranges when the page loads.

After changing on of the Selects it using AJAX to reload that partial with new dates. This change works once, after the partial is reloaded the select pickers no longer trigger any events from their actions.

```
<div id="pvDateRange">
     @Html.Partial("DateRangePartial", Model.Dates)
</div>
```

Whenever the date range gets changed it will call the AJAX.

```
$('#endDate').on('changed.bs.select', function (ev, picker) {
            $("#pvDateRange").load("/Performance/UpdateDateRanges/?accountValue=" + selectedAccount + "&startDate=" + start + "&endDate=" + end, function () {
                $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
            });
        });
```

After running this ajax function the dropdowns update with the new model properly. But now it will not trigger the on('change') event anymore.

This is the contents of that partial

```
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left">
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left">
    Start Date
    <select id="startDate" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-white" data-live-search="true" data-size="5">
        <option value="@Model.SelectedStartDate">@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", @Model.SelectedStartDate)</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.StartDates)
        {
            <option value="@item">@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item)</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 pull-left">
    End Date
    <div class="btn-group bootstrap-select">
        <select id="endDate" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-white" data-live-search="true" data-size="5">
            <option value="@Model.SelectedEndDate">@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", @Model.SelectedEndDate)</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model.EndDates)
            {
                <option value="@item">@string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", item)</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
$('#endDate').on('changed.bs.select', function (ev, picker) {...
```

with

```
$(document).on('changed.bs.select', '#endDate', function (ev, picker) {...
```

Instead of `$(document)` you can use any other parent selector of `#endDate`, as long as it's a parent that **does not get replaced by your partial reload**.

If the element you bind on gets replaced, the binding is gone and your function does not get executed.

Best practice (and [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performance)) requires you to use *the smallest selector possible* instead of `$(document)`:

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every element in the path from the event target up to the top of the document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive use of `document` or `document.body` for delegated events on large documents.